# What is meant by 'output to stdout'

Tags: linux, bash

New to bash programming. I am not sure what is meant by 'output to stdout'. Does it mean print out to the command line?

If I have a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -q  http://192.168.0.1/test -O -  | grep -m 1 'Hello'
```

it outputs a string to the terminal. Does this mean it's 'outputting to stdout' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every process on a Linux system (and most others) has at least 3 open file descriptors:

- stdin (0)
- stdout (1)
- stderr (2)

Regualary every of this file descriptors will point to the terminal from where the process was started. Like this:

```
cat file.txt # all file descriptors are pointing to the terminal where you type the      command
```

However, bash allows to modify this behaviour using [input / output redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html):

```
cat < file.txt # will use file.txt as stdin

cat file.txt > output.txt # redirects stdout to a file (will not appear on terminal anymore)

cat file.txt 2> /dev/null # redirects stderr to /dev/null (will not appear on terminal anymore
```

The same is happening when you are using the pipe symbol like:

```
wget -q  http://192.168.0.1/test -O -  | grep -m 1 'Hello'
```

What is actually happening is that the stdout of the wget process (the process before the | ) is redirected to the stdin of the grep process. So wget's stdout isn't a terminal anymore while grep's output is the current terminal. If you want to redirect grep's output to a file for example, then use this:

```
wget -q  http://192.168.0.1/test -O -  | grep -m 1 'Hello' > output.txt
```

Comment: So in my particular example, the output is being directed to terminal, which in this case is stdout?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, stdout is the terminal (unless it's redirected to a file using the `>` operator or into the stdin of another process using `|`)

In your specific example, you're actually redirecting using `| grep ...` through grep then to the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Unless redirected, standard output is the text terminal which initiated the program.

Here's a wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29